# Spring Data paginate and sort a NamedNativeQuery (JPA-Hibernate-MySql)

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm using NamedNativeQueries with SqlResultSetMappings in a Spring Data (JPA Hibernate MySQL) application, and I've been successful with the Pagination, but not with the sorting.

I've tried two forms of queries:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
  name = "DatasetDetails.unallocatedDetailsInDataset",
  resultClass = DatasetDetails.class,
  resultSetMapping = "DatasetDetails.detailsForAllocation",
  query = "SELECT dd.id, fk_datasets_id, fk_domains_id, fk_sources_id, dom.name AS domain, " +
  "src.name AS source " +
  "FROM datasets AS d " +
  "JOIN datasets_details AS dd ON dd.fk_datasets_id = d.id " +
  "JOIN sources AS src ON src.id = dd.fk_sources_id " +
  "JOIN domains AS dom ON dom.id = dd.fk_domains_id " +
  "WHERE fk_datasets_id = :datasetId " +
  "AND dd.id NOT IN (" +
  "SELECT fk_datasets_details_id from allocations_datasets_details)  \n/* #page */\n"),
```

and the second is simply using the count notation on a second query instead of using the #page notation.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
  name = "DatasetDetails.unallocatedDetailsInDataset.count",
  resultClass = DatasetDetails.class,
  resultSetMapping = "DatasetDetails.detailsForAllocation",
  query = "SELECT count(*)
....
```

Both methods work for pagination, but the sorting is ignored.

Here is the repository:

```
public interface DatasetDetailsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DatasetDetails, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<DatasetDetails> unallocatedDetailsInDataset(@Param("datasetId") long datasetId,
                                                     @Param("page") Pageable page);
}
```

And the pageable gets assembled like this:

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc(DatasetDetails.DOMAIN), Sort.Order.asc(DatasetDetails.SOURCE));
Pageable page = PageRequest.of(page, limit, sort);
```

No errors are thrown, but the sorting simply doesn't get done and no ORDER BY is generated.

Explicitly adding something like ORDER BY #{#page} won't compile.

Comment: how did you managed to get pagination on NamedNativeQuery? did you use page object in the query or did you pass it in any way in NamedNativeQuery? I notice that even though you are passing in the pageable parameter but the return type is List instead of Page.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem, where I had to dynamically filter/sort using a `NamedNativeQuery` by different columns and directions; apparently the Sorting was ignored. I found this workaround, which is not necessarily nice but it does the job:

For the repository:

```
List<MyEntity> findMyEntities(
    @Param("entityId") long entityId,
    @Param("sortColumn") String sortColumn,
    @Param("sortDirection") String sortDirection,
    Pageable page);
```

The native queries look like this:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
  @NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyEntity.findMyEntities",
      query = "select e.field1, e.field2, ..." +
              " from my_schema.my_entities e" +
              " where condition1 and condtition2 ..." +
              " order by " +
              "   CASE WHEN :sortColumn = 'name'      and :sortDirection = 'asc'  THEN e.name      END ASC," +
              "   CASE WHEN :sortColumn = 'birthdate' and :sortDirection = 'asc'  THEN e.birthdate END ASC," +
              "   CASE WHEN :sortColumn = 'name'      and :sortDirection = 'desc' THEN e.name      END DESC," +
              "   CASE WHEN :sortColumn = 'birthdate' and :sortDirection = 'desc' THEN e.birthdate END DESC" +
  ),
  @NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyEntity.findMyEntities.count",
          query = "select count(*) from my_schema.my_entities e" +
                  " where condition1 and condtition2 ..." +
                  "  and :sortColumn = :sortColumn and :sortDirection = :sortDirection"
  )
})
```

Notice in the count query I use the 2 redundant conditions for `:sortColumn` and `:sortDirection`, because once specified as `@Param` in the repository function, you need to use them in the actual query.

When calling the function, in my service I had a boolean which dictates the direction and a string that dictates the sorting column like this:

```
public Page<MyEntity> serviceFindFunction(Long entityId, String sortColumn, Boolean sortDirection, Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
    String sortDir = (sortDirection) ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize); // Spring Data 1.0 syntax

    // for Spring Data 2.0, as you were using, simply:
    // Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);

    return entityRepository.findMyEntities(entityId, sortColumn, sortDir, pageable)
}
```

The 2 things that I don't like about this are the redundant usage of the `sortColumn` and `sortDirection` params in the count query, and the way I wrote the order by statement. The reasoning for having separate `CASE` statements is because I had different data types for the columns that I sorted by, and if they are incompatible (e.g. `nvarchar` and `date`), the query will fail with the error:

> `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

I could also probably nest the conditionals, i.e. first making a case for the direction, the making an inner case for the columns, but my SQL skills only went this far.

Hope this helps! Any feedback or improvements are very welcomed.